# What is the best way to combine two audio sources into a single audio output?

Tags: audio, audio-recording, podcast, gear

A friend and I are looking to start a podcast, yea, just like everyone else on the Internet.

We are trying to determine the most practical way to combine two audio sources into a single audio output of not necessarily production quality. The combined audio will not be recorded, and used only for communication purposes. It is our intention to record our own independent tracks at different locations, and later combine them in post.

Our setup is to include a PC at each end with either skype/hangouts, audacity, a USB microphones, and a set of earphones each. The PCs will be used to record audio from our USB microphones, and to establish a line of communication between sites. How can we reasonably combine the audio out of a microphone (with a 3.5 mm and/or XLR) with the audio out of a PC (3.5 mm) so that we can hear both ourselves and the other person(s) in the skype/hangout meeting?

Comment: I like this question because I'm doing something similar with video interviews of YouTubers in other places. (We're using Skype/Hangouts for communicating, but we each have a camera pointed at us to shoot the actual HD footage we'll use in the final edited interview.) I'm confused about the last sentence of your question. It sounds like you're hoping to monitor both levels on a single computer in real time...? If so, couldn't you each monitor your own recording volume independently, and normalize the two recordings in post?

Comment: @BrettFromLA I misspoke in my original question, I've fixed the sentence so hopefully it should be clearer. I'm just wanting to listen to the PC out, while simultaneously listing to the Mic out as I record it.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, but now I'm wondering if there really is a problem. You should be able to hear your own voice just because you're speaking aloud! I don't mean that to sound sarcastic; it's just the way I envision the setup. It would be similar to talking to someone through Skype, while wearing a headset: Skype transmits your friend's voice to you through the headphones, and you hear your own voice just because you're talking.

Comment: It sounds like you just want to monitor your recording. Take a look at the [playthrough options](http://manual.audacityteam.org/o/man/how_to_set_up_audacity.html#hardplay) options in Audacity. (I'd give a more detailed answer, as an answer, but I've not used Audacity in a while and I can't check into the details right now).

Comment: I think I was just over thinking things, I guess there is no reason I couldn't use the PC as the mixer for an out from the two ins.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I misspoke in my original question, I've fixed the sentence so
>   hopefully it should be clearer. I'm just wanting to listen to the PC
>   out, while simultaneously listing to the Mic out as I record it.

If you using Windows, then just go to the

<kbd>Sound</kbd> <sub>(Right click in notification area)</sub> > <kbd>Recording devices</kbd> > Chose you device > <kbd>Properties</kbd> > <kbd>Listen</kbd> > <kbd>Listen to your device</kbd>

That would allow you to hear your recording device input in your playback device(speaker).